# Couldn't make ASPJAX working

Tags: html, ajax, asp-classic

I want to make a demo on how to combine ASP and AJAX. I have found snippets from `http://www.aspjax.com` and implemented it in my project. However, the text that should be displayed cannot be output properly.

Here's the code. Basically the same as the one in the original:
In `index.asp`

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    /** XHConn - Simple XMLHTTP Interface - bfults@gmail.com - 2005-04-08        **
     ** Code licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License      **
     ** http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/                           **/
    function XHConn()
    {
      var xmlhttp, bComplete = false;
      try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
      catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
      catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
      catch (e) { xmlhttp = false; }}}
      if (!xmlhttp) return null;
      this.connect = function(sURL, sMethod, sVars, fnDone)
      {
        if (!xmlhttp) return false;
        bComplete = false;
        sMethod = sMethod.toUpperCase();
        try {
          if (sMethod == "GET")
          {
            xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL+"?"+sVars, true);
            sVars = "";
          }
          else
          {
            xmlhttp.open(sMethod, sURL, true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST "+sURL+" HTTP/1.1");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && !bComplete)
            {
              bComplete = true;
              fnDone(xmlhttp);
            }};
          xmlhttp.send(sVars);
        }
        catch(z) { return false; }
        return true;
      };
      return this;
    }

    // doAJAXCall : Generic AJAX Handler, used with XHConn
    // Author : Bryce Christensen (www.esonica.com)
    // PageURL : the server side page we are calling
    // ReqType : either POST or GET, typically POST
    // PostStr : parameter passed in a query string format 'param1=foo&param2=bar'
    // FunctionName : the JS function that will handle the response

    var doAJAXCall = function (PageURL, ReqType, PostStr, FunctionName) {

        // create the new object for doing the XMLHTTP Request
        var myConn = new XHConn();

        // check if the browser supports it
        if (myConn) {

            // XMLHTTPRequest is supported by the browser, continue with the request
            myConn.connect('' + PageURL + '', '' + ReqType + '', '' + PostStr + '', FunctionName);    
        } 
        else {
            // Not support by this browser, alert the user
            alert("XMLHTTP not available. Try a newer/better browser, this application will not work!");   
        }
    }

    // launched from button click 
    var getMessage = function () {

        // build up the post string when passing variables to the server side page
        var PostStr = "";

        // use the generic function to make the request
        doAJAXCall('ajaxtest.asp', 'POST', '', showMessageResponse);
    }

    // The function for handling the response from the server
    var showMessageResponse = function (oXML) { 

        // get the response text, into a variable
        var response = oXML.responseText;

        // update the Div to show the result from the server
        document.getElementById("responseDiv").innerHTML = response;
    };

</script>


<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:getMessage();">Get Message From Server</button>
    <div id="responseDiv">Original Text</div>
</body>
```

So, the code tells it to replace the `Original Text` in the div with the one in `ajaxtest.asp`

In `ajaxtest.asp`

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
Response.Write "The Server time is " & Now()
```

The problem is when I click the button `Get Message From Server`, the stuff in `ajaxtest.asp` is rendered as plain text, but not in ASP. How to fix this? Is it because of the extension used is wrong?

EDIT: by plain text I mean exactly as `Response.Write "The Server time is " & Now()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the contents of your ASP page to be:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
The Server time is <%=Now()%>
```

Comment: Ha, it worked. Thanks! I didn't notice that the bracket is important in asp.

Comment: @amnbhrm - the main point being the `%>` says this is the end of a script block (just like `<%` indicates the beginning) - so `Now()` was not being processed. @Plymouth223's code has an implicit `Response.Write` in a new code block. You could have just as easily moved the `%>` from the end of the language statement to the end of all your code and it would work. Both options are equally valid, just notating in case future searchers start wondering. :)

Comment: @AnonJr Like this `<%@ Language=VBScript The Server time is Now()%>`